# Grobner basis and subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a subset and $I$ an ideal of polynomial ring $R=k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$. Is there any algorithm for deciding when $A\subseteq I$?

Answer (score 1):

Without striving for efficiency:

Use [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) to produce a Groebner basis $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$ of $I$.

Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_m$ be generators of $A$. For each $f_i$ run Buchberger with $g_1,g_2,...,g_n,f_i$. If the output is again $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$ for all $i=1,2,...,m$ (as opposed to $g_1,g_2,...,g_n,h_i$ with $h_i\neq0$) then $A\subset I$. Otherwise, $A\not\subset I$.

Comment: It is silly to run the Buchberger algorithm again, when there is a straightforward solutio for the ideal membership (which is in fact one of the steps of the Buchberger algorithm!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It is silly not to understand that Buchberger will just go directly to the step of reducing $h_i$ mod $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$. So, you are not saying anything relevant in the end, specially towards showing existence of an algorithm, and even more after I said "without striving for efficiency". I chose to say it that way for economy of words. More respect on who you call silly.

Comment: If the new polynomial is in fact in the ideal (and the ordering is correct) then yes, this will stop immediately. But if it is not, running the Buchberger algorithm will compute a Groebner basis for the new ideal, and there is  no telling how horrible this will be —I don't think one can bound the time used for this, or the size of the new basis, or anything, really. So yes, running the whole Buchberger algorithm to find a basis after adding one of the $f_i$s *is* silly.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Really? And how silly must one be to not realize that the whole Groebner basis is not necessary, but the step in which $f_i$ is reduced? People that don't have anything relevant to say but still open their mouth disgust me. Just because you like to listen to your own voice, even if it is irrelevant what you are saying doesn't imply that I need to have to listen to it. Go waste someone else's time. That is my last reply to you.

Comment: Well, that step which you mention is precisely the solution to the ideal membership problem. I don't know how silly one must be to not realize that —probably someone who is not familiar with the theory might not realize it, independently of his sillyness— but surely if you know this is would be useful to the OP and others, with various degrees of sillyness, to make it explicit. Because, as you probably have remarked, the whole purpose of this was to be helpful to the OP.

Comment: In any case, I have to say that I find your whole tone («disgust», really?!?!?! How Elizabethan) to be quite out of place. We are talking about the ideal membership problem...

Comment: @AndrewChiriac, $A$ might even be nonrecursively enumnerable and all other sorts of catastrophic things...